# C# Imitate encapsulated class during cast

Tags: c#, oop

I have following situation:

```
class TextBoxCellControl : TextBox, IDataGridViewCellControl 

class EnhancedTextBoxCellControl  : Panel, IDataGridViewCell
{ 
   private TextBox encapsulatedTextBox; 
   private Button button; 
   ...
}

class DataGridViewCell
{ 
    private IDataGridViewCellControl cellControl;

    void foo() 
    {
      TextBox tb = cellControl as TextBox;
      if (tb != null) { do something } 
    }
}
```

Class `TextBoxCellControl` and `DataGridViewCell` are out of my control and I need `EnhancedTextBoxCellControl` to inherit from Panel.

Is there some solution to this situation so `EnhancedTextBoxCellControl` could emulate TextBox which it encapsulates? Isn't possible somehow *react to the cast to TextBox* and return `encapsulatedTextBox` instead of `this` (Sort of duck typing cast)?

Comment: "When `B` is passed to the `C`" - where is this happening?

Comment: In this case `B` is put into `DataGridView` component where the `C` fragment happens.

Comment: Ok, can you please edit your question to include some code that illustrates what you're talking about; it's really not clear at the moment...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible since B must inherit from Panel and C's implementation is private.

Your only real choice is to inherit from C and perform your own logic in your inherited class' constructor.

Comment: yes, I've done exactly that (after decompiling the C/DataGridViewCell class). But was hoping for something better as this is clearly limitation of strong typing

Comment: I think this is actually more a limitation of the design of the controls than of strong typing. The control's designers most likely did not envision a scenario where this would need to occur, otherwise I suspect they would have exposed the textbox as an overridable member or add an interface to allow specification of the textbox control.